# Tests fail when executed from maven but not from Intellij

Tags: java, maven, junit, h2, spring-test

I'm writing my unit tests using JUnit, PowerMock, Spring Test and an in-memory H2 database. When I run the tests from Intellij everything runs correctly. But when I run the tests from maven (either from Intellij or from the command line) they fail.

This is my config:

```
   @EnableTransactionManagement
   @EnableJpaRepositories("my.app.repository")
   public class ApplicationTestConfiguration {
      @Bean
      public SimpleDriverDataSource dataSource() {
         SimpleDriverDataSource simpleDriverDataSource = new SimpleDriverDataSource();
         simpleDriverDataSource.setDriverClass(org.h2.Driver.class);
         simpleDriverDataSource.setUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:./ScenarioService;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1");
         simpleDriverDataSource.setUsername("sa");
         simpleDriverDataSource.setPassword("sa");
         return simpleDriverDataSource;
      }
      (...)
      private Properties hibernateProperties() {
         Properties props = new Properties();
         props.setProperty("hibernate.dialect","org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
         props.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
         props.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql","true");
         return props;
      }
   }
```

This is a sample test:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {WebAppInitializer.class,ApplicationTestConfiguration.class, DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class})
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public final class ReadTicketsTest {

    @Autowired //this is a spring JPARepository
    protected TestRepository testRepository;

    @Before
    public void init() {
         testRepository.save(engineConfig);
    }

    @Test
    public void ticketShouldBeRead() {
        //assertion code
    }
}
```

When I run the tests from intelliJ and they succeed, in the hibernate logs I see something like this:

```
Hibernate: drop table EngineConfigs if exists
Hibernate: create table EngineConfigs (id binary(16) not null, created datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL, customData MEDIUMTEXT, customerId binary(16) not null, signature varchar(255), signatureVersion integer, updated datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL, advancedConfiguration TEXT, engineConfigName varchar(255) not null, engineServiceName varchar(255) not null, locked boolean, probabilityMaximum integer not null, primary key (id))
Hibernate: select engineconf0_.id as id1_1_1_, engineconf0_.created as created2_1_1_, engineconf0_.customData as customDa3_1_1_, engineconf0_.customerId as customer4_1_1_, engineconf0_.signature as signatur5_1_1_, engineconf0_.signatureVersion as signatur6_1_1_, engineconf0_.updated as updated7_1_1_, engineconf0_.advancedConfiguration as advanced8_1_1_, engineconf0_.engineConfigName as engineCo9_1_1_, engineconf0_.engineServiceName as engineS10_1_1_, engineconf0_.locked as locked11_1_1_, engineconf0_.probabilityMaximum as probabi12_1_1_, accumulato1_.EngineConfigs_id as EngineCo1_1_3_, accumulato2_.id as accumula2_2_3_, accumulato2_.id as id1_0_0_, accumulato2_.created as created2_0_0_, accumulato2_.customData as customDa3_0_0_, accumulato2_.customerId as customer4_0_0_, accumulato2_.signature as signatur5_0_0_, accumulato2_.signatureVersion as signatur6_0_0_, accumulato2_.updated as updated7_0_0_, accumulato2_.accumulatorNumber as accumula8_0_0_, accumulato2_.description as descript9_0_0_, accumulato2_.engineConfig_id as engineC12_0_0_, accumulato2_.numberOfHits as numberO10_0_0_, accumulato2_.prize as prize11_0_0_ from EngineConfigs engineconf0_ left outer join EngineConfigs_Accumulators accumulato1_ on engineconf0_.id=accumulato1_.EngineConfigs_id left outer join Accumulators accumulato2_ on accumulato1_.accumulators_id=accumulato2_.id where engineconf0_.id=?
Hibernate: insert into EngineConfigs (created, customData, customerId, signature, signatureVersion, updated, advancedConfiguration, engineConfigName, engineServiceName, locked, probabilityMaximum, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: drop table EngineConfigs if exists
```

Which makes sense, because it is expected that it will create the database, execute the tests (hence the insert) and then drop all tables due to the @DirtiesContextAnnotation.
But when I run the tests from maven, in the hibernate logs I see something like this:

```
Hibernate: drop table EngineConfigs if exists
Hibernate: create table EngineConfigs (id binary(16) not null, created datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL, customData MEDIUMTEXT, customerId binary(16) not null, signature varchar(255), signatureVersion integer, updated datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL, advancedConfiguration TEXT, engineConfigName varchar(255) not null, engineServiceName varchar(255) not null, locked boolean, probabilityMaximum integer not null, primary key (id))
Hibernate: select engineconf0_.id as id1_1_1_, engineconf0_.created as created2_1_1_, engineconf0_.customData as customDa3_1_1_, engineconf0_.customerId as customer4_1_1_, engineconf0_.signature as signatur5_1_1_, engineconf0_.signatureVersion as signatur6_1_1_, engineconf0_.updated as updated7_1_1_, engineconf0_.advancedConfiguration as advanced8_1_1_, engineconf0_.engineConfigName as engineCo9_1_1_, engineconf0_.engineServiceName as engineS10_1_1_, engineconf0_.locked as locked11_1_1_, engineconf0_.probabilityMaximum as probabi12_1_1_, accumulato1_.EngineConfigs_id as EngineCo1_1_3_, accumulato2_.id as accumula2_2_3_, accumulato2_.id as id1_0_0_, accumulato2_.created as created2_0_0_, accumulato2_.customData as customDa3_0_0_, accumulato2_.customerId as customer4_0_0_, accumulato2_.signature as signatur5_0_0_, accumulato2_.signatureVersion as signatur6_0_0_, accumulato2_.updated as updated7_0_0_, accumulato2_.accumulatorNumber as accumula8_0_0_, accumulato2_.description as descript9_0_0_, accumulato2_.engineConfig_id as engineC12_0_0_, accumulato2_.numberOfHits as numberO10_0_0_, accumulato2_.prize as prize11_0_0_ from EngineConfigs engineconf0_ left outer join EngineConfigs_Accumulators accumulato1_ on engineconf0_.id=accumulato1_.EngineConfigs_id left outer join Accumulators accumulato2_ on accumulato1_.accumulators_id=accumulato2_.id where engineconf0_.id=?
Hibernate: drop table EngineConfigs if exists
```

Followed by the actual error:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not prepare statement; SQL [select engineconf0_.id as id1_1_1_, engineconf0_.created as created2_1_1_, engineconf0_.customData as customDa3_1_1_, engineconf0_.customerId as customer4_1_1_, engineconf0_.signature as signatur5_1_1_, engineconf0_.signatureVersion as signatur6_1_1_, engineconf0_.updated as updated7_1_1_, engineconf0_.advancedConfiguration as advanced8_1_1_, engineconf0_.engineConfigName as engineCo9_1_1_, engineconf0_.engineServiceName as engineS10_1_1_, engineconf0_.locked as locked11_1_1_, engineconf0_.probabilityMaximum as probabi12_1_1_, accumulato1_.EngineConfigs_id as EngineCo1_1_3_, accumulato2_.id as accumula2_2_3_, accumulato2_.id as id1_0_0_, accumulato2_.created as created2_0_0_, accumulato2_.customData as customDa3_0_0_, accumulato2_.customerId as customer4_0_0_, accumulato2_.signature as signatur5_0_0_, accumulato2_.signatureVersion as signatur6_0_0_, accumulato2_.updated as updated7_0_0_, accumulato2_.accumulatorNumber as accumula8_0_0_, accumulato2_.description as descript9_0_0_, accumulato2_.engineConfig_id as engineC12_0_0_, accumulato2_.numberOfHits as numberO10_0_0_, accumulato2_.prize as prize11_0_0_ from EngineConfigs engineconf0_ left outer join EngineConfigs_Accumulators accumulato1_ on engineconf0_.id=accumulato1_.EngineConfigs_id left outer join Accumulators accumulato2_ on accumulato1_.accumulators_id=accumulato2_.id where engineconf0_.id=?]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:172)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:155)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:417)
at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:122)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy64.save(Unknown Source)
at com.twelve40.gameengine.scenario.ScenarioServiceTest.init(ScenarioServiceTest.java:138)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:73)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:73)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:224)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.DelegatingPowerMockRunner$2.call(DelegatingPowerMockRunner.java:148)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.DelegatingPowerMockRunner$2.call(DelegatingPowerMockRunner.java:140)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.DelegatingPowerMockRunner.withContextClassLoader(DelegatingPowerMockRunner.java:131)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.DelegatingPowerMockRunner.run(DelegatingPowerMockRunner.java:140)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:121)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:123)
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:196)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:160)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1885)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1862)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1839)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:910)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:355)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:325)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2149)
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:78)
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:68)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4126)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:503)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:468)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:213)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:275)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:151)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1070)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$2000(SessionImpl.java:176)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2551)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:960)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:306)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:186)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:85)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:876)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:858)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:863)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1196)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:291)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy58.merge(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:434)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:414)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:399)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:371)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
... 50 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "EngineConfigs" not found; SQL statement:
select engineconf0_.id as id1_1_1_, engineconf0_.created as created2_1_1_, engineconf0_.customData as customDa3_1_1_, engineconf0_.customerId as customer4_1_1_, engineconf0_.signature as signatur5_1_1_, engineconf0_.signatureVersion as signatur6_1_1_, engineconf0_.updated as updated7_1_1_, engineconf0_.advancedConfiguration as advanced8_1_1_, engineconf0_.engineConfigName as engineCo9_1_1_, engineconf0_.engineServiceName as engineS10_1_1_, engineconf0_.locked as locked11_1_1_, engineconf0_.probabilityMaximum as probabi12_1_1_, accumulato1_.EngineConfigs_id as EngineCo1_1_3_, accumulato2_.id as accumula2_2_3_, accumulato2_.id as id1_0_0_, accumulato2_.created as created2_0_0_, accumulato2_.customData as customDa3_0_0_, accumulato2_.customerId as customer4_0_0_, accumulato2_.signature as signatur5_0_0_, accumulato2_.signatureVersion as signatur6_0_0_, accumulato2_.updated as updated7_0_0_, accumulato2_.accumulatorNumber as accumula8_0_0_, accumulato2_.description as descript9_0_0_, accumulato2_.engineConfig_id as engineC12_0_0_, accumulato2_.numberOfHits as numberO10_0_0_, accumulato2_.prize as prize11_0_0_ from EngineConfigs engineconf0_ left outer join EngineConfigs_Accumulators accumulato1_ on engineconf0_.id=accumulato1_.EngineConfigs_id left outer join Accumulators accumulato2_ on accumulato1_.accumulators_id=accumulato2_.id where engineconf0_.id=? [42102-193]
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:5389)
at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableFilter(Parser.java:1257)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimpleFromPart(Parser.java:1897)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimple(Parser.java:2045)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSub(Parser.java:1891)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectUnion(Parser.java:1709)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelect(Parser.java:1697)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:445)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:317)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:289)
at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:254)
at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:561)
at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:502)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1203)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:73)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:287)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:162)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:186)
... 99 more
```

This error is the exact same one that happens if I remove the parameter ;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1 from the connection URL and I run the tests from IntelliJ. But with the parameter, the tests work from IntelliJ but not from maven! I don't know what could be causing this, AFAIK maven shouldn't affect the execution of the tests. It seems like the connection to the database is being closed before executing the tests. Help!

Comment: I think it should be because of the Maven goals. Have you tried mvn clean install test?
I had a similar issue using powermock and it was due to the maven goals.

Comment: @itsme.cvk nope, as you can see in my own accepted answer, the problem had nothing to do with that :)

Comment: For anyone having other Maven-IntelliJ-mismatches: IntelliJ seems to load some classes on its own. I had a test-jar-dependency where the beans.xml was missing unter test/ressources/META-INF. Maven couldn't find the referenced classes, IntelliJ ran the tests without complaints.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem was with a library I was using. Since I had the library project loaded into IntelliJ, when I ran the tests manually, the library code was being used. But Maven used the library from the .m2 repository, which didn't have the .jar up to date. This out of date jar had something that was causing the creation of the table EngineConfigs to fail.
In case anyone is facing the same problem, a useful trick is to remove the ":mem" from the database connection URL and inspect the *.trace.db file that is generated when running the tests. That trace file will give you information about the real underlying issue.

Comment: I have a multi-module project and one of my jars in .m2 was outdated. I rerun "mvn clean install -DskipTests" for the whole project and then "mvn clean test" and tests passed this time.

Answer (score 5):

FWIW, something else to look at is the Java version used as the "Project SDK" in Intellij vs the Java version you are using in the CLI/shell.  For me the project was using 1.8, the shell was using 14.  Everything was fine running install from the Maven plugin, but some tests were failing in the shell.  I pointed JAVA_HOME to JDK 8 and the tests all passed.

Answer (score 3):

In my case the problem was actually about running tests in parallel vs serially, but I thought it was a Maven/IntelliJ difference because in IntelliJ the interface made it easiest to debug one test at a time, and the mvn command made it easy to run all the tests at once. Once I used [remote debugging](https://www.jambit.com/en/latest-info/toilet-papers/remote-debugging-maven-surefire-tests/) of the test in Maven, it passed, so then I thought it was a "debug" vs "run" difference, and then I remembered I had turned on JUnit parallel test execution and had a race condition in my tests with Mockito.

Comment: Thanks for the remote debugging blog reference. It was very helpful as I was having issue with test behaviour in IntelliJ and Maven CLI.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem. In my case it was because of `maven-surefire-plugin` **2.22.2**.

I solved it by using forks in maven surefire plugin using the following configuration in `pom.xml`

**Note** We can also use `<forkMode>always</forkMode>` but it is deprecated and test runs too slow as all runs in a series.

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <forkCount>3</forkCount>
                <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried every option previously written, but in my case the problem was that the order of the tests was different, so when the IDE executed everything was right, and when Maven were doing it some deletions being tested were before some other tests that needed that deleted information.

Concretely, for my Spring Boot project in which I create an H2 DB for integrations tests via scripting, the solution was to clean and re-create the whole app context after every test class. Adding @DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS) on top would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the underlying problem is the table cannot be found:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "EngineConfigs" not found; SQL statement:
```

Maybe when you run your test in Maven your database configuration parameters (URL and so on) are not the same than the specified in your code (`jdbc:h2:mem:./ScenarioService;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1` etc).

I would try to find out if some `application.properties` files (e.g. located on `src\test\resources`) is overriding these parameters in the Maven execution.

Comment: No, there are no other database configuration parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, found Intellij has some jars which are not part of .m2. Going through the error logs on maven, able to detect the mismatch

I override the IntelliJ config to use .m2 as a local repository

Preferences ->Build Tools ->Maven

Answer (score 0):

My problem is the that I missed *maven-surefire-plugin* in my pom. By adding *maven-surefire-plugin* in build->plugins->plugin solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and like others mentioned the issue was with the library/dependency. The version used by Intellij and Maven was not the same.

In my case:-
I have parent pom with Jackson dependency version 2.15.2.
In child pom the Jackson dependency was there but no version was mentioned so 2.13.5 is being used in that case by Intellij but not by maven.

So the fix is to either remove the imports from child pom.xml or explicitly mention the version in child pom as well.

Answer (score 0):

The issue I had in this exact scenario was that my version of surefire plugin was too old. Update to the latest version, that may help